# I want to create hypothetical data based on a correlation matrix

Tags: r

I am trying to write a function that creates hypothetical data. The function gets a correlation matrix (R) and an integer (n) as input values. It will create a data frame (or matrix) with n rows and the bivariate correlations among the columns must be the same as in the correlation matrix (R).

Here is what I have thus far:

My function is:

```
generate_data = function(R, n) {
r.eigen = eigen(R)
factors = t(t(r.eigen$vectors) * sqrt(r.eigen$values))
data = matrix(rnorm(n * ncol(R)), n)
data = data %*% t(factors)
return(data)}
```

And here are the outputs that I get with different n's.

Example correlation matrix:

```
R = matrix(c(1, .06, -.1, .1, .06, 1, -.51, .14, -.1, -.51, 1, .12, .1,  .14, .12, 1), ncol = 4)

> R
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3] [,4]

[1,]  1.00  0.06 -0.10 0.10

[2,]  0.06  1.00 -0.51 0.14

[3,] -0.10 -0.51  1.00 0.12

[4,]  0.10  0.14  0.12 1.00
```

And here are the correlation matrices that I can get based on the n (number of rows).

```
>  round(cor(generate_data(R, 100)), 2)

      [,1]  [,2]  [,3] [,4]

[1,]  1.00 -0.23  0.09 0.12

[2,] -0.23  1.00 -0.44 0.23

[3,]  0.09 -0.44  1.00 0.09

[4,]  0.12  0.23  0.09 1.00

 >  round(cor(generate_data(R, 1000)), 2)

      [,1]  [,2]  [,3] [,4]

[1,]  1.00  0.05 -0.11 0.10

[2,]  0.05  1.00 -0.51 0.13

[3,] -0.11 -0.51  1.00 0.17

[4,]  0.10  0.13  0.17 1.00

 >  round(cor(generate_data(R, 10000)), 2)

      [,1]  [,2]  [,3] [,4]

[1,]  1.00  0.05 -0.09 0.10

[2,]  0.05  1.00 -0.50 0.13

[3,] -0.09 -0.50  1.00 0.14

[4,]  0.10  0.13  0.14 1.00
```

My function seems to work reasonably well for large n's, but it does not work for small n's. Is there a way to make a function that works for smaller n's as well?

Hope this is clear enough. I appreciate all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rmvnorm()` function from the `mvtnorm` package. However, for small `n` the sample variation is less likely to have stabilized and you will get the small sample variation that you also saw with your own function. There's nothing you can do about that - that is randomness.

```
library("mvtnorm")
R <- matrix(c(1, .06, -.1, .1, .06, 1, -.51, .14, -.1, -.51, 1, .12, .1,  .14, .12, 1), ncol = 4)
x <- rmvnorm(n=500, mean=c(0,0,0,0), sigma=R)
```

This produces

```
cor(x)
           [,1]       [,2]        [,3]       [,4]
[1,]  1.0000000  0.1023989 -0.10946186 0.12230412
[2,]  0.1023989  1.0000000 -0.53853097 0.15985618
[3,] -0.1094619 -0.5385310  1.00000000 0.05587178
[4,]  0.1223041  0.1598562  0.05587178 1.00000000
```

which seems pretty close to what you specified with `R`. If I increase the  number of samples to 10000 I get

```
x <- rmvnorm(n=10000, mean=c(0,0,0,0), sigma=R)
cor(x)
            [,1]        [,2]        [,3]      [,4]
[1,]  1.00000000  0.05969971 -0.08121426 0.1121826
[2,]  0.05969971  1.00000000 -0.51305601 0.1247779
[3,] -0.08121426 -0.51305601  1.00000000 0.1340828
[4,]  0.11218257  0.12477793  0.13408277 1.0000000
```